# Modificar Ultimo Botão Selecionado

Tags: vba

Tenho um UserForm contendo vários botões de seleção 1-20.

Quando eu acionar o botão TingirVermelho ou TingirAzul o ultimo botão selecionado deve ser tingido de vermelho ou azul. Alguém poderia me ajudar a elaborar essa Sub?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stackoverflow. Dê uma lida nesse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para entender um pouco do funcionamento da comunidade e como elaborar melhor as perguntas.

Comment: Forneça o máximo de detalhes possível para ajudar os outros a te ajudarem. Poste um print da tela, um trecho de código que você já fez, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Será necessária a utilização de módulos de Classe para realizar isto de maneira genérica e um formulário.

[image: Árvore do VBE contendo um formulário e um módulo de classe]

#### Formulário

Um exemplo com o seguinte Formulário:

[image: Formulário contendo 1 Label e 4 CommandButton]

Em que as propriedades `Name` e `Caption` são as mesmas no exemplo da imagem.

Contendo 4 botões para os testes e um *label* para armazenar o valor do último botão clicado.

Segue o código com a inicialização do módulo de classe no formulário e tornando o label invisível.

```
Private collBtns As Collection
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'Crédito: www.andypope.info
    '         www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx
    Dim cls_btn As Classe1
    Set collBtns = New Collection
    Me.Label1.Visible = False
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "CommandButton" Then
            Set cls_btn = New Classe1
            Set cls_btn.btn = ctrl
            collBtns.Add cls_btn, CStr(collBtns.Count + 1)
        End If
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

#### Módulo de Classe

Este código é inserido no módulo de classe `Classe1`

```
    Public WithEvents btn As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub btn_Click()
    Dim ultimo_botao As MSForms.Control
    Set ultimo_botao = UserForm1.Controls(UserForm1.Label1.Caption)
    If btn.Name = "TingirVermelho" Then
        ultimo_botao.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ultimo_botao.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ElseIf btn.Name = "TingirAzul" Then
        ultimo_botao.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        ultimo_botao.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Else
        UserForm1.Label1.Caption = btn.Name
    End If
End Sub
```

Neste, o evento de cliques dos botões é declarado em `btn_Click()`.

Caso o nome do botão seja `"TingirVermelho"` ou `"TingirAzul"`, muda a cor do último botão selecionado com `.BackColor` e `.ForeColor`. Outras mudanças podem ser realizadas no botão. Veja as [Propriedades do Botão](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.controls.button_properties.aspx)

Caso contrário, armazena o nome do botão em `Label1`.

#### Resultado

[image: Resultado em Gif com LICEcap]

Comment: Muito obrigado! Deu tudo certo no meu projeto.

Comment: Caro amigo, poderia me ajudar agora com outra questão?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/325745/como-fazer-para-abrir-um-userform-com-o-mesmo-nome-de-um-bot%C3%A3o-linguagem-vba