# Como fazer para abrir um UserForm com o mesmo nome de um botão? Linguagem VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, visual-basic-6

Meu programa é formado por 20 botões e 20 UserForms. Eu queria simplificar o programa e fazer uma Sub Rotina única.

Cada vez que eu pressionar um botão, a Rotina VerificarBotaoPrecionado analisa o nome do botão e abre o UserForm com o mesmo nome do botão.

Botões: Foto1, Foto2, ..., Foto20

UserForms: Foto1, Foto2,... Foto20

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando a função `ShowAnyForm` do [Cpearson](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/showanyform.htm) é possível realizar isto com um módulo de classe.

Um exemplo com a seguinte árvore de projeto VBA:

[image: Árvore de Projeto VBA]

#### Formulário

Um exemplo com o seguinte Formulário:

[image: Formulário Exemplo]

Um formulário com dois botões com o nome do formulário que deve ser aberto.

E com o seguinte código:

```
Private collBtns As Collection
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'Créditos: www.andypope.info
    '          www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx
    Dim cls_btn As Classe1
    Set collBtns = New Collection
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "CommandButton" Then
            Set cls_btn = New Classe1
            Set cls_btn.btn = ctrl
            collBtns.Add cls_btn, CStr(collBtns.Count + 1)
        End If
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

#### Módulo de Classe

Este código é inserido no módulo de classe `Classe1`

```
    Public WithEvents btn As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub btn_Click()
    ShowAnyForm (btn.Name)
End Sub

Private Sub ShowAnyForm(FormName As String, Optional Modal As FormShowConstants = vbModal)
    'http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/showanyform.htm
    Dim Obj As Object
    For Each Obj In VBA.UserForms
        If StrComp(Obj.Name, FormName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Obj.Show Modal
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next Obj
    With VBA.UserForms
        On Error Resume Next
        Err.Clear
        Set Obj = .Add(FormName)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Err: " & CStr(Err.Number) & "   " & Err.Description
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Obj.Show Modal
    End With
End Sub
```

Neste, o evento de cliques dos botões é declarado em `btn_Click()`.

Que com o clique do botão, irá abrir o formulário de mesmo nome do Botão com a função `ShowAnyForm`.

As opções que você pode utilizar para mostrar o formulário são `vbModal` e `vbModeless`

Exemplo:

```
Private Sub btn_Click()
    ShowAnyForm btn.Name, vbModal
End Sub
Private Sub btn_Click()
    ShowAnyForm btn.Name, vbModeless
End Sub
```

#### Resultado

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Adaptei no meu projeto e funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado

Comment: Caro amigo, como faço para colar no texbox1 do userForm ativo o valor da célua A1 da planilha1?

"UserFormAtivo".textbox1.value = Sheets("plan1").range("a1").

Como faço para declarar a instrução que signifique "UserForm ativo"?