# TextBox retornando decimais diferentes no VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, textbox

Eu estou com um projeto bem simples, porém estou com um problema que não consigo resolver.

Eu acredito que o problema seja algo relacionado às configurações de idioma, porém todas as alterações que fiz até agora não me retornaram o resultado esperado.

Em um computador, ao inserir os dados de entrada e calcular, tenho a saída com decimal separado por vírgula. O resultado deste TextBox é utilizado posteriormente em outros cálculos no projeto, e neste caso o projeto  funciona normalmente.

**Imagem 1:**

[image: IMG1]

Em outro computador, ao inserir os mesmos dados de entrada e calcular, tenho a saída com decimal separado por ponto. Quando o resultado obtido é reutilizado no código para outros cálculos, o VBA simplesmente ignora o ponto. Por exemplo, trata o 2.25 como se fosse 225. Isto implica em resultados errados posteriormente.

**Imagem 2:**

[image: IMG2]

Eu já verifiquei ambos os computadores estão com as configurações de idioma como Português. O símbolo decimal global do sistema é o mesmo para as duas máquinas e no Excel configurei para utilizar o separador decimal utilizado pelo sistema.

Nos dados de entrada, como mostrado nas imagens, foi utilizado a vírgula como separador decimal.

Segue código:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If TextBox1.Value = "" Or TextBox2.Value = "" Then

        MsgBox "Preencha os campos 'Comprimento (m)' e 'Altura (m)'"

    Else

        TextBox3.Value = Round(TextBox1.Value * TextBox2.Value, 2)

        TextBox4.Value = Round(TextBox3.Value / 30, 2)

        TextBox5.Value = Round(TextBox3.Value / 100, 2)

        TextBox6.Value = Round(TextBox3.Value / 200, 2)

        TextBox7.Value = Round(TextBox3.Value / 150, 2)


    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/api/excel.application.decimalseparator

Comment: Você atribui diretamente o valor na textbox ? Pode mostrar o código que faz isso ?

Comment: Sim! Eu sei que não é uma boa prática não trabalhar com variáveis e fazer da forma que fiz, pretendo mudar isto posteriormente. Editei a pergunta com o código em questão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problema

Com um formulário de exemplo com um TextBox e um CommandButton:

[image: Userform]

Você pode verificar o tipo de dado da caixa de texto com [VarType](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function) ou [TypeName](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/typename-function):

```
Debug.Print VarType(TextBox1.Value)
Debug.Print TypeName(TextBox1.Value)
```

Que irá retornar o número `8` e `String`, respectivamente. Então você possui uma variável String e está deixando para o Excel realizar a conversão para números automaticamente, o que pode criar erros, como no caso de mudança de língua entre versões diferentes do Excel.

### Conversão

Para realizar a conversão dos dados de entrada, seja ele um número numa caixa de texto com vírgula ou ponto e transformar em número. A seguinte função pode ser utilizada num Módulo:

```
Public Function converter_numero(ByVal num As String) As Double
    On Error GoTo erros
    Dim pos_ponto As Long, pos_virgula As Long
    pos_ponto = InStr(1, num, ".", vbBinaryCompare)
    pos_virgula = InStr(1, num, ",", vbBinaryCompare)
    If pos_ponto > 0 Then
        converter_numero = CDbl(Mid(num, 1, pos_ponto - 1)) + CDbl((Mid(num, pos_ponto + 1, Len(num))) / 10 ^ (Len(num) - pos_ponto))
    ElseIf pos_virgula > 0 Then
        converter_numero = CDbl(Mid(num, 1, pos_virgula - 1)) + CDbl((Mid(num, pos_virgula + 1, Len(num))) / 10 ^ (Len(num) - pos_virgula))
    ElseIf IsNumeric(num) Then
        converter_numero = CDbl(num)
    Else
        MsgBox "Insira um número válido!"
    End If
    Exit Function
erros:
    'Criar o tratamento de erros
    MsgBox "O número " & num & " gerou o seguinte erro. " & Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

#### Explicação

1. Verifica a posição da vírgula `","` ou ponto `"."` nas variáveis `pos_virgula` e `pos_ponto`, respectivamente.
2. Verifica se a posição é maior do que zero, ou seja, se possui vírgula ou ponto.
3. Cria o número decimal somando a parte antes do separador e a após o separador, ou seja, a parte inteira e a parte decimal.
4. Convertendo o número antes do separador `CDbl(Mid(num, 1, pos_ponto - 1))` para Double, em que converte os números que estão na String da posição 1 até a posição do separador menos 1.
5. Convertendo o número depois do separador `CDbl((Mid(num, pos_ponto + 1, Len(num))) / 10 ^ (Len(num) - pos_ponto))` para Double, em que converte os números que estão na String da posição do separador mais 1 até o tamanho total da string (posição final) e depois divide por 10 elevado a quantidade de casas decimais. Por exemplo, possui duas casas decimais, 10^2 = 100.
6. Retorna o resultado da função `converter_numero`

> Obs.: O tratamento de erros pode ser realizado utilizando a função [IsNumeric](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnumeric-function)

#### Resultado

Então com o seguinte código:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Debug.Print VarType(TextBox1.Value)
    Debug.Print TypeName(TextBox1.Value)
    TextBox1.Value = Round(converter_numero(TextBox1.Value) / 30, 2)
End Sub
```

O seguinte resultado pode ser obtido:

[image: Resultado]

### Formatação

A conversão dos dados de saída também é necessária.

A formatação do resultado na caixa de texto pode ser realizada da seguinte forma após os cálculos:

```
TextBox1 = Format(TextBox1, "##0.00")
```

#### Função

E depois o ponto pode ser substituído pela vírgula com uma função num módulo:

```
Public Function converter_virgula(num) As String
    Dim str As String
    str = CStr(num)
    converter_virgula = Replace(str, ".", ",")
End Function
```

#### Exemplo

Então o exemplo ficaria:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    TextBox1 = Format(Round(converter_numero(TextBox1.Value) / 30, 2), "###0.00")
    TextBox1 = converter_virgula(TextBox1.Value)
End Sub
```

Ou

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    TextBox1 = converter_virgula(Format(Round(converter_numero(TextBox1.Value) / 30, 2), "###0.00"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Sim, neste módulo foi inserido a função, em que cada vez que precisar converter, você pode chamar esta função. Se possui muitas caixas de texto e deseja algo mais genérico. Você deve trabalhar com classes. [Como desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/325785/75104) ou [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/324404/75104)

Comment: Olá, Daniel! Ao utilizar a sua rotina, quando coloco números decimais (separados por vírgula ou ponto) tenho o resultado esperado. Porém, quando coloco um número somente com a parte inteira, retorna 0 (zero) como resultado.

Comment: Além disso, tenho o mesmo problema. Criei um arquivo novo com a sua rotina. Em uma máquina tenho resultado com vígula no TextBox, e em outro computador o resultado é com ponto.

Comment: @Clayton Veja o edit

Comment: Quando converti os dados também na saída, obtive o resultado esperado. Muito obrigado, Daniel!

Comment: Tenta formatar direto no código: TextBox3.Value = Format(Round(TextBox1.Value * TextBox2.Value, 2), "##0.00")